# USB drive doesn't auto mount

Tags: 14.04, mount, usb-drive, dd

I was trying to create a live  USB on my Ubuntu 14.04 system using the 'dd' command. After this operation, on inserting the USB stick, the device does not mount automatically as it used to get before. I tried using 'dmesg' to check if the OS recognizes the device and it works. Explicitly using 'mount' command makes the contents of the USB drive available. What might have gone wrong ?

Comment: I recommend that you try [Startup Disk Creator](//apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/usb-creator-gtk/) instead of the `dd` method.

Comment: Note: edited to remove "Fedora" as irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 1):

`dd` duplicates everything **including the blkid**.

"What might have gone wrong?" is a drive with the same blkid might already be mounted when you insert the flash drive and the system wouldn't automount what it sees as the same drive twice. If changing the blkid doesn't solve this problem, drop me a comment and I'll dig deeper.