# how to create a bootable linux pendrive from dvd

Tags: usb-drive

I have a typical problem. I have a RHELinux 5.9 DVD. I want to create a bootable PENDRIVE from this DVD.
The problem is my desktop doesnt have DVD drive. I have copied the RHEL5.9 DVD files into a pendrive from a linux PC (it wont support in creating a bootable pendrive).

How can I create a bootable PENDRIVE from the files which I have copied from the DVD?

Please guide.

Thank you

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.

Comment: I can provide multiple links that allow you to write ISO files to DVD, thumb-drives etc from windows, osx & Ubuntu (GNU/Linux), however whilst they are tested with every Ubuntu and *flavor* of Ubuntu (codlord provided 2 of 8+); there are many types of ISO file and may not apply for your RHEL system (you're off-topic; and best getting advice from Red Hat themselves)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a bootable ISO image from a bootable DVD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9304/how-to-make-a-bootable-iso-image-from-a-bootable-dvd) and [USB drive doesn't auto mount](https://askubuntu.com/q/600348/)

Comment: Not many installers will do Red Hat, Ventoy lists it as working: https://www.ventoy.net/en/distrowatch.html - Ventoy will work in either Ubuntu or Windows.

Comment: The solution to this question involves **Ventoy**, an Ubuntu Third Party App. That makes it **on-topic** for Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

I only know how to do it from an .iso image of a CD/DVD:

[Instructions for creating bootable USB on Windows.](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#10-installation-complete)

[Instructions for creating bootable USB on Ubuntu.](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#4-iso-and-usb-selection)

And if you have not already got a .iso image of the DVD then:

[How to Create ISO Files From Discs on Windows, Mac, and Linux](https://www.howtogeek.com/228886/how-to-create-iso-files-from-discs-on-windows-mac-and-linux/)

Comment: Neither SDC or Rufus work for installing Red Hat Enterprise Edition.